# Android Lollipop Activity transitions not working after changing compileSdkVersion to 23

Tags: android

After modifying my project to use compileSdkVersion 23, my projects custom Lollipop activity transition are not functioning as intended. I just get a fade in activity transition animation. Below are GIFs of the animations before and after the modifications. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[CompileSdkVersion 23 GIF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2WfHQxy1J_Ob3htWjA1U1E0WkE/view?usp=sharing)

[CompileSdkVersion 22 GIF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2WfHQxy1J_OUjB0eTMxdFFHU0E/view?usp=sharing)

### EDIT

After performing more experiments, I have noticed that this issue is not caused by the compileSdkVersion 23, but it is rather caused by setting the project with buildToolsVersion 23.0.0.  Any ideas if this is a known issue, or should I stick with this work around for now, setting buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" or any buildToolsVersion lower than 23 ?

Comment: For me, my activity transitions continue to work with androidCompileSdkVersion and androidTargetSdkVersion set to 23 if I use androidBuildToolsVersion = 21.  It seems like build tools 23 is causing the issue.  build tools version 23 adds support for the 23 sdk release, but I don't know exactly what that means.

Comment: @Scott I did not experiment with the build tools, thanks a lot for the heads up. Let me try building the project with build tools 21 or 22. And see if they are the cause of the issue.

Comment: are you building with the latest version of the gradle plugin(1.3.0)?  I'm using 1.1.0.  Not sure if that could have something to do with it.  If you're using 1.3.0, you might consider opening a ticket here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: @Scott  Am building with gradle plugin 1.2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [it's a known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183180). There are problems in the attribute handling in XML files ("with auto-versioning of resources" is said in an issue report). According to Google it has been fixed internally and it will be available in the next build tools release.